# Setting up an features server?

Tags: features

I've found dev seed's article on this issue: http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/sep/03/5-minute-feature-server/

Is it the same process for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a D7 of the feature server but you can host your D7 specific features on a D6 feature server.

Comment: Wanted to add to this by saying that there isn't an official D7 version, but there is a Dev branch (with explicit warnings not to use it) at the official fserver project and a Github project that appears to be trying to update the old fserver architecture: https://github.com/coldfrontlabs/fserver

I briefly tried out the Github project and didn't have much success, but it appears that it's being successfully used by the guys at Coldfront Labs, so something to consider.